# HTML table layout

Tags: python, html

I need to create a table with data from a mongodb document, but I cannot get it to format properly. I am using python within my HTML form.

```
 <table border="1">
  %import re
  %prog = re.compile('')
  %for item in rows:
    %prog = re.compile('item*')
    %if (prog.match(item)):
      <tr>
      <th>{{item}}</th>
      <td>{{rows[item]}}</td>
      </tr>

%end
```

Only the first item gets placed within my table however, and so my output looks like this:

[image]

How do I change it to make each item its own row in the table, rather than one item in the table and the rest just listed beneath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis means this is the first row
The   means the cell like if you have  row 1, cell 1 row 1, cell1 .
(An source that can help you out maybe to) http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_tables 
I gues you have to give every item his own  element.